# Master not starting when running Kubernetes locally via Docker

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the [Running Kubernetes locally via Docker](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.0.6/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) guide and I am unable to get the master to start normally.

**Step One: Run etcd**

`docker run --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data`

The etcd container appears to start normally. Don't see any errors with `docker logs` and I end up with an etcd process listening on 4001.

**Step Two: Run the master**

`docker run --net=host -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2 /hyperkube kubelet --api_servers=http://localhost:8080 --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --enable_server --hostname_override=127.0.0.1 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests`

I believe the this is where my issues begin. Below is the output from `docker logs`:

```
W1021 13:23:04.093281       1 server.go:259] failed to set oom_score_adj to -900: write /proc/self/oom_score_adj: permission denied
W1021 13:23:04.093426       1 server.go:462] Could not load kubeconfig file /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig: stat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig: no such file or directory. Trying auth path instead.
W1021 13:23:04.093445       1 server.go:424] Could not load kubernetes auth path /var/lib/kubelet/kubernetes_auth: stat /var/lib/kubelet/kubernetes_auth: no such file or directory. Continuing with defaults.
I1021 13:23:04.093503       1 server.go:271] Using root directory: /var/lib/kubelet
I1021 13:23:04.093519       1 plugins.go:69] No cloud provider specified.
I1021 13:23:04.093526       1 server.go:290] Successfully initialized cloud provider: "" from the config file: ""
I1021 13:23:05.126191       1 docker.go:289] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I1021 13:23:05.126396       1 server.go:651] Adding manifest file: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
I1021 13:23:05.126409       1 file.go:47] Watching path "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
I1021 13:23:05.126416       1 server.go:661] Watching apiserver
E1021 13:23:05.127148       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Pod: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D127.0.0.1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1021 13:23:05.127295       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Service: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/services: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1021 13:23:05.127336       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Node: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D127.0.0.1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
I1021 13:23:05.343848       1 plugins.go:56] Registering credential provider: .dockercfg
W1021 13:23:05.394268       1 container_manager_linux.go:96] Memory limit 0 for container /docker-daemon is too small, reset it to 157286400
I1021 13:23:05.394284       1 container_manager_linux.go:100] Configure resource-only container /docker-daemon with memory limit: 157286400
I1021 13:23:05.395019       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"
I1021 13:23:05.395040       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/empty-dir"
I1021 13:23:05.395052       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "empty"
I1021 13:23:05.395068       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/gce-pd"
I1021 13:23:05.395080       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "gce-pd"
I1021 13:23:05.395098       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/git-repo"
I1021 13:23:05.395112       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "git"
I1021 13:23:05.395124       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/host-path"
I1021 13:23:05.395136       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/nfs"
I1021 13:23:05.395147       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/secret"
I1021 13:23:05.395156       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/iscsi"
I1021 13:23:05.395166       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/glusterfs"
I1021 13:23:05.395178       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/persistent-claim"
I1021 13:23:05.395194       1 plugins.go:180] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/rbd"
I1021 13:23:05.395274       1 server.go:623] Started kubelet
I1021 13:23:05.395296       1 server.go:63] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
I1021 13:23:05.395507       1 server.go:82] Starting to listen read-only on 0.0.0.0:10255
```

**Step Three: Run the service proxy**

`docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2`

The docker logs from this step contained similar errors to what I saw in Step Two.

```
I1021 13:32:03.177004       1 server.go:88] Running in resource-only container "/kube-proxy"
I1021 13:32:03.177432       1 proxier.go:121] Setting proxy IP to 192.168.19.200 and initializing iptables
E1021 13:32:03.195731       1 api.go:108] Unable to load services: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/services: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1021 13:32:03.195924       1 api.go:180] Unable to load endpoints: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/endpoints: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

`docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
576d15c22537        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube proxy --m"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        high_pasteur
a98637c9d523        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube kubelet -"   About an hour ago   Up 34 minutes                           drunk_jones
618afb1de613        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9          "/usr/local/bin/etcd "   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                              high_yonath
```

The first error from Step Two's logs led me to believe the error may have something to do with iptables.

`iptables -L` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`docker exec -ti a98637c9d523 cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/master.json` output:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {"name":"k8s-master"},
    "spec":{
        "hostNetwork": true,
        "containers":[
            {
                "name": "controller-manager",
                "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.6",
                "command": [
                    "/hyperkube",
                    "controller-manager",
                    "--master=127.0.0.1:8080",
                    "--v=2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "apiserver",
                "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.6",
                "command": [
                    "/hyperkube",
                    "apiserver",
                    "--portal-net=10.0.0.1/24",
                    "--address=127.0.0.1",
                    "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001",
                    "--cluster-name=kubernetes",
                    "--v=2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "scheduler",
                "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.6",
                "command": [
                    "/hyperkube",
                    "scheduler",
                    "--master=127.0.0.1:8080",
                    "--v=2"
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Docker version 1.8.3

Kernel version 4.2.3

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try following the docs at head (which use a much more recent version of kubernetes) and see if you still see the same error? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md

Comment: I also opened https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16087 to get the docs updated.

Comment: I tried again using the docs at head and the result was almost the same. The "failed to set oom_score_adj to -900" warning is now gone, but I believe that is a result of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX that version of the docs suggested setting.

Comment: The thing that confuses me about your output is that when you show the `docker ps` output you don't see any of the pods that should be started from the manifest file bundled with hyperkube. Can you docker exec into the kubelet container (`a98637c9d523` in your original output) and cat `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` to see if it contains pod definitions?

Comment: Robert, I have added the output of /etc/kubernetes/manifests/master.json to the question. master.json was the only file in that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you downgrade docker version to 1.7.2 first? I did the exact what you did above with docker 1.7.2, and everything works.

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080/

{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/api/v1beta3",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/logs/",
    "/metrics",
    "/resetMetrics",
    "/swagger-ui/",
    "/swaggerapi/",
    "/ui/",
    "/version"
  ]
}

$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0141e596414c        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube proxy --   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                           nostalgic_nobel                                                                                          
10634ce798e9        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube schedule   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                           k8s_scheduler.b725e775_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_43562383            
5618a39eb11d        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube apiserve   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                           k8s_apiserver.70750283_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_e5d145be            
25f336102b26        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube controll   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                           k8s_controller-manager.aad1ee8f_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_fe538b9b   
7f1391840920        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0         "/pause"               17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_26fd84fd                   
a11715435f45        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube kubelet    17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           jovial_hodgkin                                                                                           
a882a1a4b917        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9          "/usr/local/bin/etcd   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes                           adoring_hodgkin
```

There are a couple of known issues with docker 1.8.3, especially [docker#17190](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17190). We had to workaround such issue through [kubernetes#16052](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/16052). But such changes are not cherry-picked to Kubernetes 1.0 release. From the output you posted above, I noticed that there is no pause container. Also you can run `docker ps -a` to check if some containers are dead, and copy & paste the output of `docker logs <dead-container>` here?

I will file an issue to make sure Kubernetes 1.1 release working fine with docker 1.8.3. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find a tag for 1.7.2, but 1.7.1 works as expected. I will stay back on 1.7.1 until Kubernetes 1.1 is released.